# awk and sprintf to zero fill

Tags: awk, printf

Using awk and sprintf how can I zero fill both before and after a decimal point

input

```
11
12.2
9.6
```

output

```
110
122
096
```

I can get either using these, but not both

sprintf("%.1f", $1)

output

```
110
122
96
```

sprintf("%03d", $1)

output

```
011
012
096
```

Comment: If `sprintf("%.1f", $1)` is converting `9.6` to `96` then your awk is broken. What are you REALLY doing?

Answer (score 3):

```
x = sprintf("%06.3f", 1.23)
```

Output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{x = sprintf("%06.3f", 1.23); print x}'
01.230
$
```

Comment: ok, I went with sprintf("%04.1f",$1) to get just the three numbers I need. You must have to account for the decimal when using %f.  I need 3 numbers total for output, so I use %04.1f not %03.1f

Comment: The details of what you want are largely your affair; I was primarily showing the technique for getting leading and trailing zeros (the `0` flag and a specified number of decimal places in conjunction with the `%f` conversion specification).  Note that with `%04.1`, if you format 1000, you will get `1000.0` as output, even though that's wider than 4 characters in total.  Note, too, that you get a decimal point printed.  Suppressing that is harder than it's worth; if you really don't want it, convert to integer (multiply by 10 first) and format as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

I really can't tell from your question but maybe one of these does whatever it is you want:

```
$ cat file
11
12.2
9.6

$ awk '{ x=sprintf("%03d",$0*10); print x }' file
110
122
096

$ awk '{ x=sprintf("%04.1f",$0); print x }' file 
11.0
12.2
09.6
```

Obviously you could just use `printf` with no intermediate variable but you asked for `sprintf()`.